# How to measure the initial velocity of a potato gun?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, explosions

I have made a 2m potato gun (It's like a cannon - the noise makes your ears buzz for some second :) ) Its uses alcohol as fuel. an igniter fires. then the potato will be shot out.

anyway. as it's heavy (and dangerous to ears) I can't hold it and set it to the destination.

even if I can, it won't be accurate.

I **can** calculate **when** and **where** the potato will hit the ground If I have the $v_0$ of the shot potato (using the formulas below).

$$t=\frac{2sin{\alpha}v_0}{g}$$

$$\Delta x=\frac{2 v_0^2 sin{\alpha} cos{\alpha}}{g}$$

$\alpha$ is the angle between the gun and ground.

$v_0$ (initial velocity of the potato) is related to $a$ (acceleration of potato)

and $a$ is related to $F$ (the force applied to the potato) and $m$ (mass) of the potato.

$$a=\frac{v-v_0}{t}=\frac{F}{m}$$

assuming $v_0$ to be 0 (this $v_0$ is the velocity of the potato when it is **in** the gun which is zero)

note that $v$ in the acceleration formula is $v_0$ in the $t$ and $\Delta x$ formulas.
and $v_0$ in the acceleration formula is zero. so don't take them by mistake.

thus:
$$v=\frac{Ft}{m}$$

$F$ is the force of the gun applied to the potato.
$m$ is potato mass.
and $t$ is the time during which potato gets to it's maximum velocity (acceleration becomes zero).

also $F$ is related to the volume of the explosion capsule and also to how much alcohol is poured into the explosion tube.

## Now the question is:

## **How to determine $v_0$ while knowing the followings?**

- the mass of the potato $m_{potato}$
- the volume of the explosion tube $V_{tube}$
- the amount of alcohol poured into the tube $m_{alcohol}$

assume all of the alcohol has been turned into gas and well mixed with air in the explosion tube.

a spark ignites the tube and potato is shot out.

Comment: I'm confused - it's too heavy and dangerous to shoot at all?  Why can't you set it up on a stand, measure the angle, then find some way to fire it remotely? Then you can solve your second equation for velocity once you've measured how far it went.

Comment: With the variables and assumptions you want to use, you can probably get within a factor of 10 of the actual speed. Any more accurate than that, you'll need a simulation, or a fairly sophisticated theory.

Comment: Why simulate? Just calibrate the gun - fire at a range of angles, measure the range each time, plot, fit a curve (or just interpolate) and you have a angle-range relation. Automatically accounts for all systematics! There will of course be some scatter due to variable systematics, e.g. wind, potato shape, etc.

Comment: The Combustion Enthalpy of ethanol (kJ/mol) is well known. From it calculate the amount of Enthalpy added to the air in the gun, at combustion. Then assume an adiabatic decompression during travel of the potato in the barrel. But simple experimental determination of muzzle velocity as suggested by Kyle Oman would be easier, more fun and more accurate.

Comment: I don't know why you would simulate it. That's why my comment  described how it would be better to just test it.

Comment: Even quicker - make a ballistic pendulum.

Comment: So basically... You've built a mortar minus the stand, that shoots potatoes. And you want help calculating where the potato "shell" will land?

Comment: @Brionius There are two factors to control where the potato falls. first is the amount of alcohol. second is the angle. I want to "calculate" where the potato hits ground.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast. I know I can find the initial velocity using a ballistic pendulum. but I want to calculate the initial velocity with the amount of alcohol poured into the tube.

Comment: @BlueSky Right, and as I said, I don't think you're going to get anything like an accurate answer simply using those quantities. You could assume that all the alcohol combusts, but that is very doubtful to be true in reality. The rate of expansion of the gas, and the resultant pressure on the potato won't be easy to determine. Friction as the potato exits the barrel is also a source of variation.